# How to Open Up a Contact in Console view directly?

Tags: service-cloud-console

I am trying to build a link in an external, which when clicked, would open up a contact detail view in the Console Layout.  This URL need to be dynamically generated based on phone number - nothing else.   When clicked, it would open up Salesforce Console with matching contact record opened as a tab.

How do I approach this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can direct a user to a console link that will open a specific record as a primary tab with a URL like this

http://yoursalesforceurl/console#%2F003xx0000012345

You would need to already know the contact ID though. If you are building an external link with only a phone number, you could point that link to a page with an apex controller that looks up the contact and then redirects the user. That path might look something like this:

User clicks a link to http://yoursalesforceurl/console#%2Fapex%2FgotoContact?phone=1234567890

The page named gotoContact is something like this

```
<apex:page controller="myController" action="{!redirect}"></apex:page>
```

The apex class myController has a method that looks like this

```
public PageReference redirect() { 
    String phone = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('phone');
    String contactId = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Phone:=phone][0];
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('yoursalesforceurl/console#%2F'+contactId);
    return pr; 
}
```

See also:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm

[VF controller redirect to another page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51151/vf-controller-redirect-to-another-page)

Comment: Hi, Also what would I append to navigate to console in edit mode of the case record ?

Comment: @Kiba You can use /e to get to an edit page, so something like http://yoursalesforceurl/console#%2F003xx0000012345%2Fe to get to the edit page of that record