# Invoke contact details page inside service console from outside VF page

Tags: visualforce, urlhacking, console

I have a third party application calling my VF page with parameters in URL. VF page constructor reads these parameters, perform a search on contact object and show search results. I want to open contact details page in service console after clicking on hyperlink of any one of the records displayed from the search result set above, is this possible ? I Googled it and got nothing.

Another way If I take this VF page within service console and perform manual search it works well, but then third party can't call this embedded VF page with URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer - I have a Sys Admin privilege but if I try to URL from outside console https://mydomain.salesforce.com/console#%2F0030j000004bhEc it gives me an error that "You can only view this page in Salesforce Console". But the article link you gave me helped me in forming URL link by which I could able to send parameters to VF page within console and that is what exactly I was looking for, appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

After some testing I found my original answer to be incorrect; however, I did find another post on stackexchange that works very well:

[How to Open Up a Contact in Console view directly?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101730/how-to-open-up-a-contact-in-console-view-directly)

> You can direct a user to a console link that will open a specific record as a primary tab with a URL like this
>
> http://yoursalesforceurl/console#%2F003xx0000012345

I tested this solution and was able to get it to work.